# How to mount multiple folders which share the same path pattern?

Tags: mount, bind-mount

I have multiple folders that share the same path pattern which I would like to mount them all with a single command if possible. The command I tried is:

```
sudo mount --bind /var/my/vendor  /var/www/official/*/*/vendor
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. I didn't get any specific error but it seems like I just used the wrong syntax or perhaps this is not supported at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mount --bind` takes two arguments: the path to replicate and the location where it is to be replicated. You seem to be trying to make multiple replicas; to do this, you need to issue multiple `mount --bind` commands.

```
for d in /var/www/official/*/*/vendor; do
  mount --bind /var/my/vendor "$d"
done
```

Comment: thank you very much, it runs just the way I want. Do you think it's the best place to put in rc.local so that it is run everytime the system reboots?

Comment: If the set of directories under `/var/www/official` doesn't change, then you can list them in `/etc/fstab`. But if the set can change, then a script is the only solution, and `/etc/rc.local` is an appropriate location.